# Adding a language to Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay Portal 6.1.0 GA1

SCENARIO:
After configure a portal-ext.properties like:

```
locales=es_ES,en_US
time.zones=Europe/Paris
```

And running the server OK... (only those languages and timezone)

I want to add a new language through Control Panel -> Portal Settings -> Display Settings, writting

es_ES,en_US,it_IT to AVAILABLE LANGUAGES

But I get:

```
Please enter a valid locale error.
```

I also tried to stop LR and edit portal-ext.properties but I got the same.

Can you help me?

Thx a lot!
Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASWER my own question:

I tried to add Italian (beta phase) so I tried:

```
locales=es_ES,en_US
locales.beta=it_IT
time.zones=Europe/Paris
```

But that does not work in LR Portal 6.1.0. So then I tried:

```
locales=es_ES,en_US,it_IT
time.zones=Europe/Paris
```

And solved

Answer (score 5):

Looks like issue is with number of Languages you are selecting from Display Settings. As after adding only 2 locales(es_ES,en_US) from portal-ext.properties, when you go to Control Panel -> Display Settings, it's displaying around 10+ languages in Current. So after adding English to current and save it's trying to validate all the languages with the locales= values provided in portal-ext.properties.

And when it tries to validate language other than the one you've provided in portal-ext.properties it will give error.
What you can do here is,
- First remove all the entries from Current back to Available
- Add only "English(ES)" to Current one
- Save

Reference : [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/34939541)